# Socket.IO : connect_error event not emitted

Tags: javascript, socket.io

i have a simple socket.IO server, and a client that connects to it :

```js
    socket = io('http://localhost:' + port + '/chat', {
        reconnection: false,
        query: {
            name: username
        }
    })
```

it works perfectly fine, but when i tried implementing the behavior of that client when the server cannot be found (which i simply test by just loading the page without starting the server), i faced a simple issue : the `connect_error` event is not emitter. Right after i initialize the socket, i have this code :

```
socket.on('connect_error', ()=>{
    console.log("Error! ")
})
```

as i said, this callback is never called, i get an error message in the console stating that the request returned 404 (`http://localhost:5454/socket.io/?name=AA&EIO=4&transport=polling&t=O2__7JM`), but my custom error message is never printed.
So, what am i doing wrong ? Isn't this event supposed to be fired if the connection with the server couldn't be established ? If not, how do i handle this situation (i.e. how do i make socket.io call a certain callback if the connection failed ?)